# upgrade k8s cluster version

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet

I've upgraded our kubernetes cluster before to 1.22.7 and get nodes says so.

`kubectl get nodes`

> ubd   Ready    337d   v1.22.7

Now I wanted to upgrade to 1.23.7 so I did the following steps on master and all workers

- sudo apt-mark unhold kubeadm && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y kubeadm=1.23.7-00 && sudo apt-mark hold kubeadm
- sudo kubeadm upgrade node (upgrade plan/apply on master)
- sudo apt-mark unhold kubeadm && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y kubelet=1.23.7-00 && sudo apt-mark hold kubelet
- sudo systemctl daemon-reload
- sudo systemctl restart kubelet

So new version kubeadm installed:

> kubeadm version: Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.7"

```
kubectl -n kube-system edit cm kubeadm-config
```

says kubernetesVersion: v1.23.7

All good so far.

But then

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Still says 1.22.7 is used!

ubd   Ready                                       223d   v1.22.7

Strange! Why is the old version still displayed when all other commands like kubeadm version say v1.23.7??